# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Error

Tags: java, encryption

I am getting the error "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption." when I am trying to decrypt a text string. I have 2 programs one that encrypts the string and one that decrypts the string. They both use a common jar file. The encryption program can decrypt the encrypted string correctly, so I know the decrypt function works correctly. I have verified that the string to be decrypted in the second program is correct. I don't understand why the second program doesn't work. Incluced is common module code. The first program just call the encrypt function and to verify calls the decrypt function. The second program is just a call to the decrypt function.

```
public class EncryptionUtility {

    private static byte[] key_data = { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08,
            (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x10 };

    private static byte[] iv_data = { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08,
            (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x10 };

    private static Cipher aes = null;

    static {
        try {
            aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private EncryptionUtility() {
    }

    public static String encrypt(String target) throws GeneralSecurityException {

        if (aes != null) {
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(key_data, "aes");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv_data);
            aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            return base64Encode(aes.doFinal(target.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        } else {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("Encryption failed to initialize.");
        }
    }

    private static String base64Encode(byte[] encrypted) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        if (aes != null) {
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(key_data, "aes");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv_data);
            aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            return new String(aes.doFinal(base64Decode(encrypted)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } else {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException("Encryption failed to initialize.");
        }
    }

    private static byte[] base64Decode(String property) throws IOException {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(property);
    }
```

Comment: The scenario you describe works fine on my machine (as expected). Check if both programs really use the same jar (i.e. a jar file that applies the same key and the same IV).

Comment: **Security warning**: the usage of a static = fixed IV is **unsecure** in most use cases, use a random IV instead. Please do not use the code above in real production environments, thanks.

Comment: The first iten I checked was for multiple jars. There is only 1 copy of the jar file and I created a new project set and started from source just to ensure that maven wasn't the problem. I also, deleted my repository copy before rebuildinng from the source.